# Change order of divs in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Mobile View**

[image]

I have upload my desktop and mobile view depective picture. I have given numbers to the div. I want to change the order of div as given in the below image.

**Expected Behaviour**

[image]

Can anyone please help me here to change the order of divs in mobile view?

Answer (score 0):

Use `bootstraps visible-xs hidden-xs` classes to define html for both desktop and mobile views

Comment: all the divs should be visible. Am not talking about hidden. Am asking about the changing the order of divs in mobile view

Comment: Using a single html code without hiding anything it is very complicated to implement@user2349508

Comment: if you hide the divs it wont visible right? i want all the 6 divs to be displayed. But need to change the order. Need to shuffle the divs

Comment: thats what i am saying write html  in visible-xs as per mobileview order and write html in hidden-xs as per desktop view order

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) and [css order property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div[class^="d"]{
            border: 3px solid black;
            width: 100px;
            height: 80px;
            margin: 5px auto;
        }
        .ld{
            border: 0;
            width: 100px;
            height: 90vh;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width:400px){
            .d2{
                order: 2;
            }
            .d3{
                order: 4;
            }
            .d4{
                order: 1;
            }
            .d5{
                order: 3;
            }
            .d6{
                order: 5;
            }

        } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ld">
        <div class="d1">1</div>
        <div class="d2">2</div>
        <div class="d3">3</div>
        <div class="d4">4</div>
        <div class="d5">5</div>
        <div class="d6">6</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```